Google's Automatic "Malicious Software" False Positives?
So we run 40 or so websites and they are quite secure. We have Netacea for bot management, who is one of the top 2 forester pics for botmanagement. We also have Akamai for WAF, CDN, and another layer of Botmanement. We have account managers at both places and they provide reports for us. In addition, we aren't even running our websites on web servers, but rather have containerized microservices that spin up and spin down on demand.
Given all of this, every few months what seems to happen is we get a flag from google saying "Hey, your site has malware" -- at this point our website managers know to immediately send in an appeal, and so far, 6 out of 6 times this has happened, the appeal has lifted the flag within 1-2 days without anybody actually doing or changing anything.
In addition, we looked wherever we could in the code base and in what little infrastructure we have and found absolutely nothing that would indicate malware.
Finally, when we asked google "Hey, what did you actually see here that flagged your software?" they remained EXTREMELY close-lipped and gave us a cookie cutter response not more helpful than what you see here: Malicious content detected by google webmasters tool
So my ask is this:
Do any of you have experience with this? Do false positives happen a lot?
Does anybody know what we should/shouldn't do to help this not happen again?
Has anybody had any luck getting some light shed on how this actually works from google? Like maybe there is a contact point or method I haven't tried yet to get some information on how to avoid this.

I experienced it twice very long ago. Like about seven years ago or so. One time it was a compromised WP extension. It added hidden links to the site. Probably for SEO purposes.
Another time I just neglected to update WP for quite a few... years. And, of course, got hacked. This time, it was a spam-relay. It deployed an smtp and relayed spam through it. I got contacted by the VPS company and they asked me to fix it. I had to demolish the site (I didn't care about that site) and then contacted different kinds of spam blacklists to remove the IP from the lists.
My conclusion: those notices from Google rarely misfire. Better go take a look at your stuff.
